# Setting up chrome debugger in dockerized node application returns `WebSockets request was expected`

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, remote-debugging, chrome-remote-debugging

I'm having trouble setting up chrome debugger within a dockerized node application.

I've tried following https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/11591 to no success.

My application does run on PORT, but my chrome debugger always displays `WebSockets request was expected` when on localhost:9229. I have a suspicion that it has something to do with my index.js listening on PORT, but I'm unsure.

Can someone please help? Thanks!

(I have a .env file with DOCKER_WORKING_DIR and PORT defined.)

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:8
ENV DOCKER_WORKING_DIR="/usr/local/app"
WORKDIR ${DOCKER_WORKING_DIR}
COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN npm install --quiet
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  api:
  build:
    context: ../../.
    dockerfile: docker/images/app/Dockerfile
  command: npm run start-dev
  environment:
    PORT: ${PORT}
    DOCKER_WORKING_DIR: ${DOCKER_WORKING_DIR}
volumes:
  - ../../.:${DOCKER_WORKING_DIR}/
  - ${DOCKER_WORKING_DIR}/node_modules
ports:
  - "${PORT}:${PORT}"
  - 9229:9229
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js",
  "start-dev": "nodemon --watch ./src -x \"npm run start-debug\"",
  "start-debug": "node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 index.js",
},
```

index.js

```
const server = require('./src/server');
server.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question. I used a node inspector chrome extension and then everything worked https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nodejs-v8-inspector-manag/gnhhdgbaldcilmgcpfddgdbkhjohddkj?hl=en